# Struggling with Secured Python Websockets

Tags: python, nginx, ssl, websocket, cloudflare

I'm trying to set up a secure websocket server.
However, whenever I try and secure it using SSL I end up with errors [note: it works if I don't have SSL enabled]
With this current setup the client says `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)`

Server:

```
import websockets, asyncio, ssl

async def hello(s, path):
    data = await s.recv()
    await s.send(data)
    print("Got data:", data)

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
ssl_context.load_cert_chain('origin.pem', 'private.pem')
start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "0.0.0.0", 87, ssl = ssl_context)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Client:

```
import websockets, asyncio, ssl

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
ssl_context.load_verify_locations('origin.pem')

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect("wss://socket.ganer.xyz/gsdgsdfg", ssl = ssl_context) as s:
        await s.send("Test")
        print("Got data:", await s.recv())

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

My setup runs on port 87, with `wss://socket.ganer.xyz` pointing to a VPS running nginx which redirects it to my server at home

Cloudflare Worker: https://ganer.xyz/s/yQKyhz

Cloudflare Certs [these work for my main website]: https://ganer.xyz/s/iqmjim

Nginx VPS Config: https://ganer.xyz/s/FiGzaK

EDIT, FIXED: Basically, I scrapped the worker and redid some NGINX stuff. Port 80 goes to nginx which redirects to port 87 on my home server. Socket.ganer.xyz is simply an A record that points to the VPS

New config: https://ganer.xyz/s/X2IKnJ

And Replaced the SSL context on the client with this, `ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)`

Comment: What is the content of `origin.pem`? Make sure that it you include all intermediate certificates too.

Comment: It's the cloudflare origin certificate https://ganer.xyz/s/DUCV9Z

Answer (score 1):

> It's the cloudflare origin certificate

Cloudflare origin certificates are only trusted by Cloudflare. They are not issued by a publicly issued CA and that's why they are not trusted by Python by default.

> ```
> ssl_context.load_verify_locations('origin.pem')
> ```

This line does not make connections using the certificate trusted. Instead this trusts any certificates **issued** by the given certificate. Since this is a leave certificate it cannot issue any certificates. You would need to trust the relevant root CA instead and make sure that the server sends all relevant intermediate certificates.

Comment: What should I do to fix this?

Comment: @Ganer: to cite myself: *"You would need to __trust the relevant root CA instead__ and make sure that the server sends all relevant intermediate certificates."*

Comment: yes but how do I do that, I'm basically clueless in all of this

Comment: @Ganer: The relevant root CA can be found [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/origin-ca#4-required-for-some-add-cloudflare-origin-ca-root-certificates). Use this in `ssl_context.load_verify_locations` instead of your `origin.pem`.